# Solve $x-1 \ge \sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I got as far as $-1 = \sin(x)-x$.

I don't know what to do next. Pretty sure I am forgetting some simplification rule.

Comment: $y>sin(x)$ you know how to solve and then $x-1=y$. Does it help you?

Comment: There is no analytic solution.

Comment: What about $x=xsin({\alpha})$? You can then substract/add sinuses and btw for your logarithmic question it works as well.

Comment: @VitaliPom I get $\arcsin(x-1) = x$ or $\arcsin(y) = y+1$. What do I do next?

Comment: Solve $x = \sin{x}$ for $x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, then $y \geq \sin{x}$ for every $y \geq x$.

Comment: @Nicolas how do you do that analytically?

Comment: Sorry yeah my bad, in my formula you get $lg(x)$. I dunno how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no analytical solution to the problem.

Numerical solution suggests $x\ge 1.9345632$

Comment: How do you know when there's no analytical solution to a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let:

$$a_{n+1}=\sin(a_n)+1$$
$$b_{n+1}=\sin(b_n+1)$$

Then the point of equality $p$ is given by:

$$p=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\bigg[\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n\bigg]+1$$

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: You're solving $x-1=\sin(x)$ which leads to $x=\sin(x)+1$, or subbing $x=t+1$ gives $t=\sin(t+1)$. You can then iterate to find the solution to either of these

Comment: How do you iterate?

Answer (score 0):

As already said in comments and answers, there is no analytical solution.

By inspection or graphing, you should notice that the first root is "close" to $\frac{2\pi} 3$. So, using Taylor expansion around this value
$$\sin(x)-x+1=\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)-\frac{3}{2} \left(x-\frac{2 \pi
   }{3}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)^2\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, an *approximation* is
$$x=\frac{6+3 \sqrt{3}+2 \pi}{9} \approx 1.94215$$ Using on more term in the expansion will give a quadratic equation in $\left(x-\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)$ and the result would be $\approx 1.93480$ which is quite close to the "exact" value given by Mohammad Riazi-Kermani.

Answer (score -1):

Others have suggested there is no analytical solutions, however;

Let $x=\frac{5\pi }{2}$, then $\frac{5\pi }{2}-1\geq \sin(\frac{5\pi }{2})=1$. Just an example, you can go from here.

It seems there are infinite solutions.

Comment: Everyone else seems to be trying to solve the problem of finding _all_ solutions. To do that, you want to find the smallest solution $r$ so that you can say the interval $[r,\infty)$ is the solution set. You can of course pick off an infinite sequence of individual numbers that satisfy the inequality without ever coming close to the minimum.

Comment: @DavidK: How do you know the solution set is an interval?

Comment: @LeeMosher Isn't $x - \sin (x) - 1$ a strictly increasing function? And it does have a root between $0$ and $\pi.$

Comment: Yes, that's how I would prove it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems analytic solution is more subtle .so,by numerical methods ,You can try Newton-Rephson method ,

- F(X)=sinx-x+1=0.
- X2=x1-(f(x1)/f'(x1)). X1 is initial point.
- x1 =(a+b)/2, where f(a)*f(b)<0.
- as per required accuracy iteration can be done.